# How do you remove link underlines in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, text-decorations

I'm trying to create a HTML signature but whatever I try, all my links keep an underline when I send it with Outlook (2007). The strange thing is: When I copy the rendered code (copied from browser to Outlook) it doesn't show any underline. However, once I sent it, it seems all formatting is gone and the underline appears again. If I sent the identical thing from any other client to Outlook this does not happen and it shows correctly.

A few samples of what I've tried:

```html
<a href="#" style="border-style:none;text-decoration:none;">Link 1</a><br/>
<a href="#" style="border-style:none!important;text-decoration:none!important;">Link 2</a><br/>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration: none">Link 3</a><br/>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><span style="text-decoration: none">Link 4</span></a><br/>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">Link 5</a></br>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; text-decoration: none !important"><span style="text-decoration:none; text-decoration: none !important">Link 6</span></a><br/>
<a href="#" style='text-decoration:none;text-underline:none'><span style='text-decoration:none; text-underline:none'>Link 7</span></a><br/>
```

I'm really out of ideas how to create a clickable link in Outlook that does not has an underline.. Even though 'underline-color:white' is an option. It is not supported by all browsers, which makes it a bit useless.

Any suggestion is welcome!

*Via http://devspot.nl/testfile.html you can try all variations yourself.*

---

**How it is displayed when copied from Chrome into Outlook:**

[image]

**And how it is displayed when received in Apple Mail (Note: Gmail in Chrome-browser is identical)**

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998378/how-do-i-remove-link-underlining-in-my-html-email ---> go through this link will help u

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WORKING UPDATE

As the CSS method never worked, I suggested the OP to take a look at the link below which shows you how to change the hyperlink styling inside Outlook itself:

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/remove-underline-and-changing-hyperlinks-color

-- NOT WORKING FOR OP --

Try this:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;">Link</a>
```

The reason this works is because Outlook strips the !important style, leaving the regular style to do the job.

Comment: I wished it worked, but sadly it doesn't. All links, all 8 (incl. yours) have an underline when received in any mail client (Gmail, Outlook, Apple Mail). I've checked all Outlook settings but couldn't find anything related, although it should be something regarding Outlook itself..

Comment: Can you take a look at this non-css method. I'm pretty sure I've been able to remove the hyperlink using the following - http://www.msoutlook.info/question/remove-underline-and-changing-hyperlinks-color

Comment: I think Outlook somehow forces general styles on top of your own hard-coded CSS styling. Because when I create a new style, underline deselected, and apply it to the links everything worked. So uhm.. You know. Create a new answer with that link and I'm gonna select it as 'answer' :)

Comment: Glad it worked Sander! I have updated my post instead of creating another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<a style="color:#E3A216; text-decoration:none;">
  <span style="color:#E3A216; text-decoration:none;">
    <font color="#E3A216">
      Link 1
    </font>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Edit: You forgot the href="#" which didn't turned it into a link. So it still doesn't work sadly..