# How to remove text-decoration from gmail signature

Tags: css, gmail, html-email, html4, text-decorations

Context: My client asked me to create an email signature with links to twitter, Facebook and LinkedIn.

My problem: When I copy/paste the email signature of the browser to an email, the `text-decoration: none` doesn't work for the client. So I managed to solve the problem on Outlook by copying/pasting the signature of mail from my computer to that of the client with TeamViewer. But for other messengers, the problem persists despite good integration from Outlook.

I did not find any answer in the other posts.

Here is the link of my email signature: https://www.cntd-avocats.fr/medias/org-1428/signatureMail/annabelle-texier.html

the problem in image :

[image: signature de mail]

```html
<p style="  margin-top:12px;">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cntd-avocats/" style="text-decoration:none;width: 33px; height:18px">
        <img style="width: 33px; height:18px" border="0" alt="linkedin" src="https://medias.azko.fr/org-1428/signatureMail/img/pictos-linkedin.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/CntdAvocats" style="text-decoration:none;width: 43px; height:18px">
        <img style="width: 43px; height:18px" border="0" alt="twitter" src="https://medias.azko.fr/org-1428/signatureMail/img/pictos-twitter.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/CNTD-Avocats-319317948727137/" style="text-decoration:none;width: 33px; height:18px">
        <img  style="width: 33px; height:18px" border="0" alt="facebook" src="https://medias.azko.fr/org-1428/signatureMail/img/pictos-facebook.jpg" />
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Maybe take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998378/how-do-i-remove-link-underlining-in-my-html-email

Comment: Try removing the width and height from the `a` tag and see if its still doing it.

Comment: i tried to remove the width and height of `a` but it's the same ..
i tried to add !important after `text-decoration:none` but it's dosn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please try to write like this:

```
<style>
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

http://www.hyperlinkcode.com/remove-hyperlink-underline.php

Comment: thanks but your anwser is for Removing  all Hyperlink Underlines Single Page not on email signature

Answer (score 0):

You can remove link underlining in email signatures in Gmail by using a non-Chrome browser to set up the signature, as follows:

1. Open your email signature in a non-Chrome browser, e.g. Firefox
2. Copy the entire signature - select all (Ctrl/Cmd-A), copy (Ctrl/Cmd-C)
3. Open Gmail in the same non-Chrome browser (this is important - Chrome's user-agent stylesheet will interfere if you perform this step using Chrome)
4. Select the Gear icon > See all settings
5. Paste the signature into the email signature field
6. Save

You can now open a Chrome browser and compose a new email. The email signature should appear without the underlines. If it doesn't work the first time (as it for me), delete the draft, reload Gmail and compose again.