# Remove blue links in HTML signature on Outlook on WIndows

Tags: html, windows, hyperlink, outlook, signature

No matter what I try Outlook on Windows adds blue links to my HTML email signature - how can I remove them...

```html
<td style="margin:0;padding:0;padding-left:8px;font-family:Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;font-size:11px;">
  Mobile:
  <a href="tel:0456666555" style="border:none;text-decoration:none!important;color:#9d9fa2;">
    <font color="#9d9fa2">0456 666 555</font>
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

Your example gave me an idea as a solution, and it seems to work for the colour but not the underline.

```
<td style="margin:0;padding:0;padding-left:8px;font-family:Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;font-size:11px;">
  Mobile:
  <a href="tel:0456666555" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#9d9fa2;">
    <span style="text-decoration:none;color:#9d9fa2;">0456 666 555</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

You wrap the link around a `<span>`.

On inspecting the signature in Gmail, Outlook strips the link of any styling. So it looks like there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer that works for me! I am also amazed it works!

It involves duplicating any styling on the `<a>` tag and then adding an `!important` attribute to it.

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;">BOOK NOW</a>
```

Outlook will strip out the style with `!important` attribute leaving the regular style, thus no underline. The `!important` attribute will overrule the web based email clients' default style, thus leaving no underline.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21172586/1298155)